# Expectation of a Function of a RV Problem

Tags: self-study, random-variable, expected-value

> **Problem.** Let $X$ be a random variable (either continuous or discrete) that takes nonnegative values. Prove or provide a counterexample to the following statement: There does not exist an X such that $E(X)$ is finite and $E(X\ln(X + 1)) = +\infty$.

I'm shooting for a counterexample first:

For continuous, let $f(x)$ be the pdf of $X$. If we let $g(X) = X\ln(X + 1)$ then we have that
$$E(X) = \int_0^{\infty}xf(x)dx < \infty ~~~~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~~~~ E(g(X)) = \int_0^{\infty} x\ln(x+1)f(x)dx = +\infty. \tag{1}$$

For discrete, let $p(x)$ be the pmf, and we have the similar cases

$$E(X) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}xp(x) < \infty ~~~~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~~~~ E(g(X)) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}x\ln(x+1)p(x) = +\infty. \tag{2}$$

Then we can either find some $f(x)$ or $p(x)$ which satisfies $(1)$ or $(2)$. I've tried to isolate either $x$ or $x\ln(x+1)$ by say letting $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{x\ln(x+1)}$, and so on. Does anyone have any ideas, or is it actually true that no such $X$ will satisfy both expectations?

**EDIT:** Using comments advice, we have the divergence of the r.h.s of (1) when

$$x\ln(x+1)f(x) = \Theta\left(\frac{1}{x}\right).$$

Now we look at the asymptotic proportionality of $f(x)$ such that

$$f(x) = \Theta\left(\frac{1/x}{x\ln(x+1)}\right) = \Theta\left(\frac{1}{x^2\ln(x+1)}\right).$$

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Hint: look at integration by parts.

Comment: Since $\log(x+1)$ diverges at $+\infty$ it should not be very difficult to find a $t$ counterexample.

Comment: @StephanKolassa From an interview a few days ago. Not sure if that falls under self-study? Will add if so, let me know.

Comment: @StephanKolassa For IBP do you mean to take $g(x) = x\ln(x+1)$. Then we get $\int f(x)g(x)dx = x\ln(x+1)f(x) - \int x\ln(x+1)f'(x)dx$, which doesn't seem like it helps much?

Comment: Interview questions definitely fall under [tag:self-study], so please do add the tag. Regarding the approach, one integral we know something about is $\int xf(x)\,dx$... does this suggest something about how to cut $\int x\ln(x+1)f(x)\,dx$ up?

Comment: It might also help to edit in the steps you have outlined in the comments.

Comment: Modify your approach a little: since $\int x\log(x+1) f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ is supposed to diverge, which obviously happens when $x\log(x+1)f(x)$ is asymptotically proportional to $1/x,$ see what happens when $f(x)$ is asymptotically proportional to $1/x$ divided by $x\log(x+1).$ You will need to see whether the expectation $\int x f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ is finite.

Comment: @whuber See my edit. While this satisfies the requirement for $\int x\ln(x+1)f(x)dx$, we no longer that that $\int xf(x)$ finite. Am I missing something entirely obvious?

Comment: Yes: in concluding the integral is infinite, you mistakenly extended the integration down to an improper lower limit, which is irrelevant to the question.  This integral does not diverge as the upper limit grows: see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%28x%5E2+log%28x%29%29+dx+for+x+%3D+2+to+infinity for instance.